# Angular router-outlet is appending rather than replacing the entire component

Tags: angular

The problem is that when I route it append rather than replace the entire component.

my app-routing.module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {MainLayoutComponent} from './pages/main-layout/main-layout.component';
import {AdminLayoutComponent} from './pages/admin-pages/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'app-layout', component: MainLayoutComponent},
  {path: 'admin-layout', component: AdminLayoutComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
```

My app-component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alpha-Monitor (v 2.0)</title>
  <base href=".">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

What I get when I transition:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdsqY.png)

What a have in `devTools`:

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFJtc.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you access in the browser localhost:8080/ angular looks in your routes for a route matching / and redirects to that component.
As you don't have any entry in your routes for the route /, and as slash is present in all your routes as they start with a slash (/app-layout and /admin-layout) it will add both elements to the page when you visit localhost on the browser.

As such in order to solve this you can do the following:

In your routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent},
  {path: 'admin-layout', component: AdminLayoutComponent}
];
```

Comment: This way when you visit localhost:8080/ it will show MainLayoutComponent and when you visit localhost:8080/admin-layout it will show AdminLayoutComponent.

Comment: You must add `pathMatch: 'full'` to empty-path route because empty string partially matches any route and other routes will never be reached. Or place this redirect at the end of the list after all named routes.